# Draw transparent circle on top of the google map

Tags: android, google-maps

i'm beginner to android platform. I want to draw transparent circle on top of the google map, around users current gps location can anybody help me to providing some guidelines.. it is very helpful..

Comment: look at https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/maps/model/Circle

Comment: If you try to draw something transparent, it won't be visible, so better not draw it at all ;)

Answer (score 0):

try this code

```
//here map is GoogleMap object

 CircleOptions circleOp =new CircleOptions();
 circleOp.center(new LatLng(currentLat, currebtLong));
 circleOp.radius(10000);
 circleOp.fillColor(Color.TRANSPARENT);
 map.addCircle(circleOp);
```